# 500 Internal Server Error on centos

Tags: php, centos-web-panel

My request only last 3 min and return 500 Internal Server Error. Here is my apache error_log file:
`Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: ...`
Can anyone help me how to solve it? I already set execution time but still not working: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`
Here is my code

```
public static function compress($source, $destination)
{
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
  Tinify\setKey(env('API_KEY'));
  Tinify\fromFile($source)->toFile($destination);
}
```

My code only using tinypng api to compress image, i think it's too long

[image]

Comment: 500 generally implies that there is a code error somewhere in your code, we can't help fix it unless you show us the relevant code.

Comment: http://serverfault.com

Comment: Put it in your post.

Comment: Don't post code in the comments please, edit your question and paste it there, thx

Comment: okay i already fix it

Answer (score -1):

It cause of
1. If you kept sleep function e.g. sleep(5000);
2. PHP version7 make it 5.6 something.

If you did fix please share your answer. 
Thank You.